# Problem with AlertDialog (crash when trying to catch exception)

Tags: android, exception, dialog, crash

I want to catch exception when my XML doesn't parse. Because I have no influance on the XML being created, I wan't to catch exceptions when something goes wrong (like a wrong tags, weird signs and so on).

I've created following code, but it causes a crash. I've added LogCat under the code. I don't quite understand what LogCat is telling me... Anyone has a hint to help me? Thanks

```
private void getVacatures(){
    functie = getIntent().getIntExtra("Functie", 0);
    stat =getIntent().getIntExtra("Statuut", 0);
    regio = getIntent().getIntExtra("Straal", 0);
    opl = getIntent().getIntExtra("Opleiding", 0);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(JobList.this);

        try {
            Log.e("in try", "try");
            /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */

            URL url = new URL("C:/Users/hannelore.deblau/Desktop/TESTXML.xml");
            System.out.println("URL: "+ url);

            /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/ 
            vacatureWebservice vs = new vacatureWebservice();
            xr.setContentHandler(vs);

            /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
            xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            /* Parsing has finished. */

            /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
            arrVacatures = vs.getVacatures();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            builder.setTitle(R.string.Fouttitel);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.XMLfout);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.Ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            }); 
            builder.create().show();
        }
        //runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}
```

In onCreate() I do this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); // This code is in the main UI activity class

    handler.post(runnable= new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            getVacatures();
            runOnUiThread(returnRes);
        }
    });
    Thread thread = new Thread(null, runnable, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
```

LogCat with error: http://pastebin.com/X5uk9cex

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update the Ui from a worker thread called `MagentoBackground` . You need to do your Ui work from within the main thread. Try to use  `Handler`.

Here is some tutorial for `Handler`

- [Tutorial 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html)
- [Tutorial 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329124624/http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/using-handler-for-long-time-operations-in-android/)

Again in your are using an url  like

```
  URL url = new URL("C:/Users/hannelore.deblau/Desktop/TESTXML.xml");
```

This `URL` will never invoke .What you need to do is to keep your xml in a web server then access it.

**Edited Your onCreate**

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.your_view);
          runnable= new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
        // Your code 
    
    try{ /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
    
                URL url = new URL("C:/Users/hannelore.deblau/Desktop/TESTXML.xml");
                System.out.println("URL: "+ url);
    
                /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    
                /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/ 
                vacatureWebservice vs = new vacatureWebservice();
                xr.setContentHandler(vs);
    
                /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
                xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                /* Parsing has finished. */
    
   

                 /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
                    arrVacatures = vs.getVacatures();
          runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    
    
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
    //here error comes
    //here also you need to use this code
       runOnUiThread(nullRes);
        }
                        }
                };


    Thread thread = new Thread(null, runnable, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();

}
```

**Now here is your exception code**

```
private Runnable nullRes= new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(JobList.this);
 builder.setTitle(R.string.Fouttitel);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.XMLfout);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.Ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            }); 
            builder.create().show();

        }
    };
```

Comment: For the URL, I know, this is just for testpurposes, because my original link works. Still I can't predict if there is ever going to be a wrong XML. That's why I wan't to catch it.

Comment: Added `onCreate()`..May be there is format regarding brace({ }) issue.

Answer (score 0):

RuntimeException isnt a subclass of Exception so your catch clause wont trap it. You could change your catch clause to catch Throwable which is the common superclass. This would at least solve the problem of your code not handling it. There are probably other problems at play though regarding the cause of the exception.

The exception is being thrown because there is not handler/looper for the dialog to use. You need the dialog code to run on the UI thread.

Comment: However, if I debug, it goes over the dialog code, but doesn't show. his this also to do with Exception not being a subclass of RuntimException?
Changing Exception to Throwable gives me the same crash.

Comment: Actually looking again I doubt that the exception is even being thrown in your try block. The problem is that the Dialog code isnt being run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using AndEngine or something like that, and this sub is called from a sub-Thread instead of main activity. That's why you get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Try call that sub outside of any thread (maybe UIThread or UpdateThread). Or, if you HAVE TO call it within those thread, call a Handler by the Main Activity and post it:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); // This code is in the main UI activity class
```

And when you want to call it:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    getVacatures();
});
```

Comment: I called it in `onCreate` using this method: `runnable= new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
          
          getVacatures();
          runOnUiThread(returnRes);
         }
        };` I don't know how to melt those two together?

Comment: @Hannelore: That's strange! If you call it from onCreate, I wonder why that exception was thrown. Did you try the one I wrote? Using handler? And, what exactly class of onCreate method you call from?

Comment: I've added my onCreate-code with handler, it still causes the same crash... I call an onCreate method in an Activity that extends ListActivity

Comment: @Hannelore So what class do you call it from? Is it inherited from a context?

Comment: @W.N. the class I use for the XML is an ArrayAdapterClass that's used inside an Activity class...

Comment: @Hannelore So, onCreate is a sub (event) of ArrayAdapterClass, not the Activity? So, you must declare a Handler variant within the Activity class, then pass it to the ArrayAdapterClass, then use that Handler to Post the Runnable. P/s: How do you highlight the keywords in comment, please tell me?

Comment: The onCreate is inside the Activity class , underneath the onCreate I hav an ArrayAdapterClass.

Comment: Just checking but... The 3rd comment implies that you are calling the onCreate() method directly. You shouldnt do this. The onCreate() is called by the Android system to initialize your activity.

Comment: Sorry, it's out of my ability now. Hope that anyone else could help you. Good luck!

Comment: @fleetway76 I think I've expressed me wrong. I have an onCreate method where I call the XML parse method.